# Setting horizontalAlignment doesn't fully right align PageXofYBuilder

Tags: java, jasper-reports, text-alignment, dynamic-reports

I have created a report using dynamic reports and add a page number component and set its horizontal Alignment as right. But in printed report, page number doesn't seem to be fully right aligned.

[Check this image to see the alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUpXC.png)

**Note :-** No right padding for page number and no trailing white spaces in page number expression.

versions used :-
dynamicreports - 3.0.2
jasperreports - 4.8.0

Comment: I don't understand why people down voting without leaving a comment. Please do leave a comment so that I can improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of time spent on debugging and checking source code of dynamic reports I found the issue. I am posting this for anyone who find its helpful.

When we add PageXofYBuilder, what dynamic reports actually doing is create two text fields for 'x' and 'y'. If the component is right aligned then text field for 'x' is right aligned and text field for 'y' is left aligned with fixed width. The width of text field for 'y' is calculated as width required for a 6 digit number based on the selected font, font size and horizontal padding.

Check out the below code of pageXofY method in the class ComponentTransform which is responsible for creating the page number field in jasper design for more details :

```
 private DRDesignList pageXofY(DRIPageXofY pageXofY, DefaultStyleType    defaultStyleType) throws DRException {
        TemplateTransform templateTransform = accessor.getTemplateTransform();
        DRIReportStyle pageXofYStyle = pageXofY.getStyle();
        if (pageXofYStyle == null) {
            pageXofYStyle = accessor.getTemplateTransform().getTextStyle();
        }
        DRDesignStyle style = accessor.getStyleTransform().transformStyle(pageXofYStyle, true, defaultStyleType);
        Integer height = templateTransform.getPageXofYHeight(pageXofY, style);
        HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment = templateTransform.getPageXofYHorizontalAlignment(pageXofY, style);

        DRStyle newStylePageX = new DRStyle();
        newStylePageX.setParentStyle(pageXofYStyle);
        newStylePageX.getPadding().setRight(0);
        DRPen pen = new DRPen();
        pen.setLineWidth(0f);
        newStylePageX.getBorder().setRightPen(pen);
        DRStyle newStylePageY = new DRStyle();
        newStylePageY.setParentStyle(pageXofYStyle);
        newStylePageY.getPadding().setLeft(0);
        newStylePageY.getBorder().setLeftPen(pen);

        DRTextField<String> pageXField = new DRTextField<String>();
        pageXField.setAnchorNameExpression(pageXofY.getAnchorNameExpression());
        pageXField.setBookmarkLevel(pageXofY.getBookmarkLevel());
        pageXField.setHyperLink((DRHyperLink) pageXofY.getHyperLink());
        pageXField.setPrintWhenExpression(pageXofY.getPrintWhenExpression());
        pageXField.setStyle(newStylePageX);
        pageXField.setHeight(height);
        pageXField.setHeightType(pageXofY.getHeightType());
        pageXField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        pageXField.setValueExpression(new PageXofYNumberExpression(pageXofY.getFormatExpression(), 0));

        DRTextField<String> pageYField = new DRTextField<String>();
        pageYField.setAnchorNameExpression(pageXofY.getAnchorNameExpression());
        pageYField.setBookmarkLevel(pageXofY.getBookmarkLevel());
        pageYField.setHyperLink((DRHyperLink) pageXofY.getHyperLink());
        pageYField.setPrintWhenExpression(pageXofY.getPrintWhenExpression());
        pageYField.setStyle(newStylePageY);
        pageYField.setHeight(height);
        pageYField.setHeightType(pageXofY.getHeightType());
        pageYField.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        pageYField.setValueExpression(new PageXofYNumberExpression(pageXofY.getFormatExpression(), 1));
        DRIGroup pageYEvaluationGroup = accessor.getGroupTransform().getFirstResetPageNumberGroup();
        if (pageYEvaluationGroup == null) {
            pageYField.setEvaluationTime(Evaluation.REPORT);
        }
        else {
            pageYField.setEvaluationTime(Evaluation.GROUP);
            pageYField.setEvaluationGroup((DRGroup) pageYEvaluationGroup);
        }

        int pageXofYWidth = templateTransform.getPageXofYWidth(pageXofY, style);
        switch (horizontalAlignment) {
        case LEFT:
            int pageXWidth = StyleResolver.getFontWidth(style, 4);
            int pageYWidth = pageXofYWidth - pageXWidth;
            if (pageYWidth <= 0) {
                pageYWidth = 10;
            }
            pageXField.setWidth(pageXWidth);
            pageXField.setWidthType(ComponentDimensionType.FIXED);
            pageYField.setWidth(pageYWidth);
            pageYField.setWidthType(pageXofY.getWidthType());
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            pageYWidth = StyleResolver.getFontWidth(style, 6);
            pageXWidth = pageXofYWidth - pageYWidth;
            if (pageXWidth <= 0) {
                pageXWidth = 10;
            }
            pageXField.setWidth(pageXWidth);
            pageXField.setWidthType(pageXofY.getWidthType());
            pageYField.setWidth(pageYWidth);
            pageYField.setWidthType(ComponentDimensionType.FIXED);
            break;
        default:
            pageXField.setWidth(pageXofYWidth / 2);
            pageXField.setWidthType(pageXofY.getWidthType());
            pageYField.setWidth(pageXofYWidth / 2);
            pageYField.setWidthType(pageXofY.getWidthType());
            break;
        }

        DRList listPageXofY = new DRList();
        listPageXofY.addComponent(pageXField);
        listPageXofY.addComponent(pageYField);
        return list(listPageXofY, DefaultStyleType.TEXT, null, null);
    }
```

StyleResolver.getFontWidth() method

```
protected static int getFontWidth(DRDesignStyle style, int columns) {
        double width = getFont(style).getStringBounds("m", context).getWidth();
        return (int) Math.ceil(width * columns) + getHorizontalPadding(style);
    }
```